# Let the Google drive has the lowest priority for internet usage when Google drive is at background

Tags: windows, google-drive, cloud, cloud-storage

Is it possible to let Google drive only uses the spare traffic to sync?

For example, when I am using chrome and opened a webpage, I want google chrome to enjoy the priority of wifi and quickly download all the content of the webpage. Then, after the webpage being loaded, I want Google drive to continue its job.

Currently, when Google drive is running, it takes the majority of traffic, making every other internet activity very slow. I have to manually pause syncing while I am browsing, and manually turn it back on when I am not using the internet.

Note that it is not about limiting the bandwidth or limiting the upload speed of google drive. For example, if I limit the bandwidth of Google drive at 50%, then, I might still experience lag while watching a video.

---

One solution found: most windows computer comes with a building Intel app called "killer control center" that prioritize the access to internet.

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: @harrymc Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows does not contain a mechanism for prioritizing access to the network
or specifically to the internet. This requires third-party utilities,
that unfortunately are commercial.

Below are the two best-known such utilities:

- [NetLimiter](https://www.netlimiter.com/)
  ($29.95). Documentation:
  [Priorities](https://www.netlimiter.com/docs/basic-concepts/priorities).
- [NetBalancer](https://netbalancer.com/)
  ($49.95).
  See "Priorities and limits" in
  [Features](https://netbalancer.com/features).

Comment: +1 I think it is a very simple utility I don't know why they are paid. To me I just manually turn the cloud app on/off to prioritize the network traffics.

Comment: I find that most windows computer comes with a building Intel app called "killer control center" that prioritize the access to internet.

Comment: Netlimiter works pretty well!